# Оправданность использования bigint вместо timestamp

Tags: sql, postgresql

Есть практика хранить время в виде `unix_timestamp`. Я же предпочитаю `timestamp`. 
Какая прелесть хранить данные в машинно-понятном виде? Скорость, меньше места или просто сила привычки?

Comment: в заголовке упомянут `bigint`. это так и задумано?

Comment: ну да тип поля bigint

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Думаю что дело в привычке, с тех времен когда мат.сопроцессоры были медленными, а timestamp хранился как число с плавающей точкой.

Сейчас, ИМХО, единственная ситуация когда unix_timestamp предпочтительнее - это если данные извне приходят в таком виде.

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, что основная причина - наличие legacy-кода в приложениях, использующих базу.